# Position Arrow underneath absolutely positioned bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an absolutely positioned bar at the top of my website that is either visible or invisblie, in fact sliding down from the top with a jquery function. Underneath that bar is a little arrow I want to be always visible. So if the bar is hidden the arrow should be at the top of the browserwindow. If the bar is visible I want it to be positioned under the bar just like in this fiddle … http://jsfiddle.net/aRZn7/

HTML:

```
<div id="metaBar"></div>

<div class="meta-arrow">
    <div class="down"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#metaBar {
    position:absolute;
    background:#000;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    /*display:none;*/
}

.meta-arrow {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.down {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    right:30px;

    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:8px solid transparent;
    border-right:8px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid #000;
}
```

But consider that when I'm using jquery slideDown() to slide down the metabar I want the little arrow to move with it.

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a no fuss approach, you can introduce a bar container to contain both your arrow and your black bar, like so:

**CSS**

```
.bar-container {
    position:relative;
}

#metaBar {
    position:relative;
    background:#000;
    width: 100%;
    height:30px;
    display:none;
}

.meta-arrow {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.down {
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    right:30px;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-left:8px solid transparent;
    border-right:8px solid transparent;
    border-top:8px solid #000;
}

/* test stuff */

a#slidedown {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    padding:10px 20px;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="bar-container">
<div id="metaBar"></div>

<div class="meta-arrow">
    <div class="down"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aRZn7/29/

Comment: thank you, nice approach. Only thing is that I need the #metaBar to be positioned absolute. When I position it relative it pushes the rest of the page downwards. I want it to be placed absolutely above the rest of my header! So exactly this is my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/aRZn7/30/

Comment: @Matt you can position the bar container absolutely, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/aRZn7/31/

Answer (score 1):

Put the arrow inside the bar and use `top: 100%;` (or an equivalent pixel value). It will be displayed outside the bar just as it is now, as long as you don't use `overflow: hidden` on the bar.

Comment: @Matt: So don't set it to `display: none`. If you really want to hide it even though it's outside the visible viewport, put a container around the actual bar content and hide that.